# Javascript focus measurement

Tags: javascript, focus

I'm looking for a Javascript library to be able to measure the time a div (or any other object) has been in "focus" (as in: the browser is showing and the window is focused; not the normal Javascript focus event).

Do you know if something like that exists ? or something similar I can tweak?

Edit:
Ok. Rephrased to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: Javascript is not capable of following the users eye movements.

Comment: Bah. How boring! I'm not sure if JS can know if the browser window is in active/focused or not - but it certainly can't tell if the browser window is visible or obcured by other windows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure I understood your question right away! . .

If you mean 'in focus' as in 'visible on the screen' you can figure this out via window extents and  body.scrollTop and absolute position of divs computed recursively from offsets in parents.

Comment: @Scott: sounds awfully simple when you put it that way :)